# Calculating power of a number in MS Access query

Tags: mysql, ms-access

I need to convert a MySQL query into my MS Access DB.

The query i use in MySQL is;

```
USE horsedb;
SELECT  Event_id, Place, Money,pow(money,2)/2 
AS New_Money 
FROM prize 
ORDER BY place,event_id;
```

In MS Access i have tried using ^ as Power Of, for example;

```
SELECT  Event_id, Place, Money, 
' ^ 2 (money,2)/2)'
AS New_Money 
FROM prize
ORDER BY place,event_id;
```

The problem is with the result the column New_Money has the equation in it..

```
Event_id   Place    Money   New_Money
101          1      120      ^ 2 (money,2)/2)
102          1      10       ^ 2 (money,2)/2)
103          1      100      ^ 2 (money,2)/2)
401          1      1000     ^ 2 (money,2)/2)
101          2      60       ^ 2 (money,2)/2)
```

Comment: Try removing the single quotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were pretty close in your original attempt. The correct answer is

```
SELECT Event_id, Place, Money, money^2/2 AS New_Money 
FROM prize ORDER BY place,event_id
```

Despite what the other answers say, there is no `POWER()` Function in Access SQL.

Answer (score 0):

use POWER

```
ex : SELECT POWER(yourvalue, 3) AS Result1
```

here its document http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174276.aspx

Comment: There is no `POWER()` Function in Access SQL.